# Local variables in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, distributed-computing

Working on new project that uses Flink and trying to understand some object decisions.

So in a RichFlatMapFunction, there is a hashmap that is an instance variable. Every-time flatmap is entered, the hashmap is immediately cleared and then used. I understand that flink separates flatmap functions on different threads, but is there any risk for accessing the hashmap in this way? Also should this hashmap be transient that way it is localized to only that thread?

Furthermore later on in the flatmap there are local variables of Iterator created. So is there a better way than initializing these objects every-time and then just waiting for the garbage collector to clean them up?

I think this question maybe more of a distributed systems question, but any information or links to reading will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Every-time flatmap is entered, ...". Are you saying that every time the `flatmap()` method is called, you clear the hashmap and then use it while processing the incoming value?

Comment: @kkrugler yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

There is no risk of Flink concurrently calling your `RichFlatMapFunction.flatMap()` method, so you don't need to worry about creating thread-local variables.

Normally you would declare a class `private transient Map<blah, blah> myVariable`, and then initialize it in your `RichFlatMapFunction.open()` call.

Regarding GCing of a per-call Iterator that you're creating - in the words of one of the best programmers I know (Bill Atkinson), "Measure, then Optimize" :) If your workflow is running slower than you require, it's time to dig out some performance measurement tools, but I would bet against any slowness caused by GC activity for your iterator.